# when to call optimize function while using zend_search_lucene?

Tags: php, symfony1, full-text-search, zend-search-lucene

I am using zend_search_lucene for indexing documents and I am in dilemma on calling optimize function.

Please let me know if optimize function is to be called after indexing or while searching.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not call it that often. Depending on how fast your index changes, you can call it every few hours or days. I usually have a once-a-day cronjob that does index optimizing.

Comment: Hi but on index optimizaTION, I saw addition of disc space .... it is showing more memory consumption on calling optimization function.

Comment: This function optimises for faster searches, yes it needs quite some memory to do that.